# Is it possible for an unreferenced object to stay in memory and invoke target action?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, selector

I have a class like this:

```
class Example: UIView {
    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame); 
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss(_:)));
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
    }
    func show(parentView: UIView) { 
        parentView.addSubview(self);
    }
    @objc func dismiss(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        self.removeFromSuperview();
    }
}
```

And then I want to call it like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear();
    Example.init(frame: self.view.bounds).show(parentView: self.view);
}
```

The view is displayed with a red background as expected. But when I tapped on the view, nothing happened. The dismiss function is not even called.

But if do like this:

```
var example : UIView!;
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear();
    example = Example.init(frame: self.view.bounds);
    example.show(parentView: self.view);
}
```

The tap works fine. I suspect this is because the object is sort of destroyed along the way? But it still exist within the `UIView` subview stacks? I thought it weren't completely destroyed because it was referenced by the parent view subviews right? Can I make the target action works without creating a local variable to hold the object (just referenced by the subviews)?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this with logs and breakpoints yet?

Comment: @ZonilyJame yes I have. I put breakpoint on the `self.removeFromSuperview()` line, but it never gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create an ivar for the instance of `Example`.  By calling `show(parent:)` you ended up adding it to the view hierarchy, which retains it. So it stays in memory.

If I run your sample code in a brand new Xcode single view application project, it works just fine without an ivar.  My code is:

```
import UIKit

class Example: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss(_:)));
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func show(parentView: UIView) {
        parentView.addSubview(self);
    }
    @objc func dismiss(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        self.removeFromSuperview();
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        Example.init(frame: self.view.bounds).show(parentView: self.view);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

And what happens when I run this code:

[image: clicking the red view makes it disappear]

So it seems like clicking the red `Example` view makes it disappear just as you intended it to.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. But if it works in your case, I probably had something wrong in my code. It's true that the code I posted above is a dumbed down code in order to just present the real issue. I'll take a look again at my code, and will let you know if I find something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works because a superview is always the owner of its subviews. If that weren't true, most screens on your iPhone would be very empty because they don't have an owner. For this reason, it is also sufficient to use weak references for outlets.

Comment: Alright, thanks for confirming it. Before, I was just afraid that that is not the case, because of the symptom it produces.